# XSL transformation where input xml file has xmlns defined or absent

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a xml input which sometimes may have or may not a xmlns defined.
How to resolve such a case with just a single xsl for successful transformation?
Below are inputs at both cases and the xsl **(1.0)**

**Input file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<input version="2.1">
    <Data>
        <Object class="PM" operation="create" name="japan">
            <p name="Active">1</p>
        </Object>
        <Object class="AM" operation="create" name="india">
            <p name="Active">0</p>
        </Object>
    </Data>
</input>
```

**XSL without namespace definition:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="Data">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Object[@class='PM' or @class='AM']">
                <xsl:sort select="@name"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Object[not(@class='PM' or @class='AM')]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Object[@operation = 'create' ]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="class">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(@class,'/TIME')"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input xml with namespace defined:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<input version="2.1" xmlns="xyz.xsd">
    <Data>
        <Object class="PM" operation="create" name="japan">
            <p name="Active">1</p>
        </Object>
        <Object class="AM" operation="create" name="india">
            <p name="Active">0</p>
        </Object>
    </Data>
</input>
```

Although the xslt doesnt throw error, the output is not transformed as expected:(

How to handle above case possibly with a single xsl or any ideas are welcomed.

Comment: Is it a *specific* namespace that can either be there or not - or can they just throw any random namespace at you?

Comment: Yes, for now there is only one namespace or its not present.. Not yet come across random ones..

Answer (score 3):

If you need to handle any element with a particular local name regardless of namespace in XSLT 1.0 then you need to use an idiom like `*[local-name() = 'Object']`, or alternatively you could base your patterns on the structure instead of the names (i.e. rather than "match an element named Object" you say "match any element that is three levels down from the root"):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/*/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[@class='PM' or @class='AM']">
                <xsl:sort select="@name"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(@class='PM' or @class='AM')]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*/*/*[@operation = 'create' ]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="class">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(@class,'/TIME')"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Write your XSLT so that the first thing it does if the input isn't in a namespace is to create a copy of the data that IS in a namespace (or vice versa). Then the rest of the code doesn't need to worry about the distinction.

Comment: Hi Michael... The already present framework doesn't give an option to create another copy of input data..

Comment: What? I thought you were using XSLT?

Comment: Sorry, what i meant was the input is fixed and i could use xslt only once where i perform the necessary logic on input.

Comment: @user1529282 I think what Michael is hinting at is a two-phase transformation - first strip out the namespaces, storing the result in a variable, then apply your main templates to that with `<xsl:apply-templates select="exslt:node-set($resultOfPhase1)"/>`. If you search Stack Overflow you'll find examples of this technique that you can learn from.

Answer (score 1):

> Yes, for now there is only one namespace or its not present.. Not yet
>   come across random ones.

In such case you could define a prefix for the namespace, and adjust your stylesheet to call both versions of any element "in parallel":

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xyz="http://xyz.xsd">

<xsl:template match="Data | xyz:Data">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Object[@class='PM' or @class='AM'] | xyz:Object[@class='PM' or @class='AM']">
            <xsl:sort select="@name"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Object[not(@class='PM' or @class='AM')] | Object[not(@class='PM' or @class='AM')]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Object[@operation = 'create' ] | Object[@operation = 'create' ]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="class">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(@class,'/TIME')"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```